# How to get the result from a popup inflated activity without dismissing the dialog (Emoji style)?

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, popup, emoticons

I am successfully getting the result from a popup inflated activity back to the parent one; however, the dialog box is showing emoticons which needs to stay on screen until the user click back button or outside the box layout. Is there a way to return all selected values and keep the dialog showing? Here is a snippet of the original working code:

Manifest tags for Popup activity:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.packagename.Emoticons"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
```

Click for popup:

```
void showEmojis() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this.getBaseContext(), Emoticons.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 99);
    }
```

Action on emoji click from dialog activity:

```
   OnItemClickListener myOnItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            EmoticonItem face = (EmoticonItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Intent in= getIntent();
            in.putExtra("FACECODE", face.getTitle());
            setResult(99, in);
            finish();

        }
    };
```

Parent activity handling the result:

```
if (resultCode == 99) 
    {
        String faceCode = imageReturnedIntent.getExtras().getString(
                "FACECODE");

        mEmoticonHandler.insert(" " + faceCode + " ",getFaceByCode(faceCode));
    }
```

Comment: The purpose of a dialog is to popup and be dismissed. If you are doing something completely custom, show us some more code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Its a chat window where user clicks for smileys, the activity is inflated in a popup dialog with emojis, each click adds the smiley to the edittext field in the parent activity and then dismisses. I need it to stay alive for faster emoji use.